# Java Runtime exec time-heavy command

Tags: java, mysql, runtime, task, exec

I need to execute command to dumb mysql database in linux (debian), when I perform this command manually it takes about 10 minutes, I need to make this automatic. I am coding in Java.

I am just wondering if this will work without any problems even if the execution will take 10 minutes to complete:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "mysqldump --add-drop-database --flush-privileges --all-databases -h localhost -u root -p" + Deamon.localrootpass + " | mysql -h " + Deamon.slavehost + " -u " + Deamon.slaveuser + " -p" + Deamon.slavepass + ""});
```

Will this work ? Or I should make java.lang.Process variable and wait till the task finishes and then terminate the process ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's a _dumb_ MySQL database?

Comment: P.S. It will **not** work - the pipe (`|`) is a shell construct. You need to get the `OutputStream` from the command and pass it as the `InputStream` to the other command. You're also going need some threads...

Comment: I once used [this code](http://www.bosit.be/blog/2008/03/29/dumping-a-mysql-database-from-java/) to dump MySQL using JDBC. May this helps you too. Would definitly be a more ellegant solution.